# struts wrong path in action url

Tags: forms, url, action, struts-1

i have index page with redirect link to main page

```
<logic:redirect forward="welcome"/>
```

now my url looks like `http://localhost:8081/task5/ProductsAction.do?method=categories`

on main page i have form

```
<form action="/ProductsAction.do">
   <button name="method" value="subCategories"></button>
</form>
```

but url changes to `http://localhost:8081/ProductsAction.do?method=subCategories`

here is my action mapping in struts config

```
   <global-forwards>
        <forward name="welcome" path="/ProductsAction.do?method=categories" />
    </global-forwards>
    <action-mappings>

        <action parameter="method" path="/ProductsAction" name="ProductsForm"
            scope="request" validate="true"
            type="com.epam.app.presentation.action.ProductsAction">
            <forward name="categories" path="/pages/categories.jsp" />
            <forward name="subCategories" path="/pages/subCategories.jsp" />
            <forward name="products" path="/pages/products.jsp" />
        </action>
```

why does '/task5/' disappear from url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using an absolute URL in a `<form>` tag.

Comment: hm then how should look relative path? i thought if path starts with "/" it is relative

Comment: @SeeinRed That's backwards. It's just like the file system; "/" is the root.

Comment: i tryed also "ProductsAction" without slash , but then folder path was added to url like "http://localhost:8081/task5/pages/ProductsAction.do?method=subCategories" , i got it working by writing url in action like "/task5/ProductsAction.do?method=save" is it correct?

Comment: @SeeinRed Yes. You should be using the link tag to avoid having to add the extension and the context.